# Суффикс н глаголов

Tags: морфология, морфемика, морфемный-разбор

В глаголе "высохнет" суффикс н, корень -сох, основа -высохн. Но что за суффикс н? Формообразующий? Нигде не могу найти информацию. Может, это тот же суффикс, что ну? Напр. высохнуть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сох/ну/ть — вы/сох/ну/ть — вы/сох/н/ет.

СОХНУТЬ, нсв. 1. (**св. высохнуть**). Становиться сухим, теряя влагу (о том, что мокро, сыро).  Глагол совершенного вида образуется от глагола несовершенного вида с помощью приставки ВЫ.

**Словоизменительная схем для глагола "высохнуть**" [высохнуть | morfologija.ru](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C)

При образовании **прошедшего времени** основа инфинитива усекается на суффикс НУ: вы/сох/ну/ть — вы/сох, вы/сох/л/а.

При образовании **будущего простого**  времени основа инфинитива усекается на гласную У, а Н сохраняется: вы/сох/ну/ть — вы/сох/н/ет.

Comment: А суффикс-то слово- или формообразовательный?

Comment: Список формообразующих суффиксов глаголов известен (ТЬ, Л и др.), суффикс НУ туда не входит. В то же время важно понимать, что суффикс НУ имеет два разных значения: " В современном русском языке суффикс -НУ- используется в двух группах глаголов с разным значением. Одна из этих групп – глаголы одноактного действия, которые имеют совершенный вид (стукнуть, крикнуть), а другая – глаголы со значением состояния, непрерывной деятельности, приобретения и утраты качества, признака (вянуть, гаснуть), которые имеют несовершенный вид". http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik/suffiks-66819.html

Comment: -НУ- как раз может быть формообразовательным: ахнуть, дунуть, лизнуть и т. д. И причем совершенно точно — регулярный и продуктивный, образующий формы совершенного вида глаголов первого спряжения. Сравните с словообразовательным -НУ- (см. мой ответ). А по возрасту-то он древний, да ))

Comment: Как раз не может. Глаголы совершенного и несовершенного вида - это разные глаголы, а не разные формы одного глагола.

Comment: Не совсем точно )) Это отдельная дискуссия, но в подтверждение своих слов скажу: всё, о чем я писал (про с/о и ф/о -ну-), есть в замечательной книжке "Толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц русского языка" Т. Ф. Ефремовой.

Comment: Кстати, вот [здесь](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4) можно почитать о виде: "В русском языке категория вида является двойственной, имеющей черты как словоизменительной, так и словообразовательной".

Comment: Смутная тема,  разные школы.  Школьникам и студентам   в этой дискуссии не стоит участвовать. Всё зависит от определения. Если суффикс выражает чистую грамматику, то он формообразующий, а если еще и семантика слов разная, то  что тогда ? (Дуть - дунуть, изменяется вид, появляется значение однократности действия.) И тогда суффикс НУ  следует считать словообразовательным - тоже по определению, которое верно в определенных пределах, но достаточных  для обычных пользователей (не академиков). Чтобы у у этих пользователей   сформировались хотя бы какие-то  устойчивые знания.

Comment: Вот поэтому все  учебники, учебные сайты суффикс НУ обходят сторонкой,  когда дают перечень формообразующих суффиксов.

Comment: Ну, мне просто показалось, что вам стоило бы более эксплицитно написать о типе суффикса. А в остальном, кажется, у нас схожие точки зрения.

Comment: А  почему вы тогда в ответе суффикс НУ называете словообразовательным, а потом цитируете Ефремову, которая считает его формообразующим?

Comment: Вы невнимательно прочитали; пожалуйста, посмотрите еще раз 3-й комментарий, где явно противопоставлены с/о и ф/о.

Comment: Ахать — ахнуть: здесь ф/о -ну-. Сухой — сохнуть: здесь с/о. Два разных случая, если вы про это.

Answer (score 3):

**Вы-сох-н-ет.**
В данном случае суффикс *-н-* (он же — ***-ну-***, ср.: *высох-ну-ть*) — словообразовательный (вы не зря включили его в основу). Он образует глаголы несовершенного вида со значением постепенного усиления какого-либо состояния, названного мотивирующим словом, например: *виснуть, киснуть, тихнуть* (ср. также их формы: *вис-н-ет, кис-н-ет, тих-н-ет*) — именно так образован глагол *сохнуть*, от которого и произошло слово *высохнуть*.